# Java instance for comparable

Tags: java, generics

Why is it legal to create `new Box();` and  `new Box<Integer>();`? Is it because `Box` is comparable?

```
public class Box<Comparable> {
  private boolean compareTo(Box b) {
    return (this.y > b.y);
  }

  double x=0;
  double y=0;

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Box a = new Box();
    Box b = new Box<Integer>();
    System.out.println(a.compareTo(b));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information about what you you're trying to achieve. Currently, it may have multiple explanation for your question. Please read : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think you are trying to achieve below:                                                                    class Box<T extends Comparable> {

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have declared the class with a generic type parameter. This is not the same as implementing the Comparable interface:

```
public class Box<Comparable> {

}
```

Is the same as:

```
public class Box<T> {

}
```

Which is not the same as:

```
public class Box<T> implements Comparable<T> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final T o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Because the type parameter is unbounded, it will accept any type. So you can use an `Integer` or a `String`:

```
public class Box<T> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box a = new Box();
        Box b = new Box<>();
        Box c = new Box<Integer>();
        Box d = new Box<String>();
    }
}
```

The reason why you can create a new `Box` without specifying the type is because of backwards compatibility. The new `Box` would have the raw type `Box<T>`. It is **bad practice** and should be avoided.

You can read more about Raw Types [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)

If you wanted to enforce that the type parameter implements Comparable, then you can do:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Box<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box a = new Box();
        Box b = new Box<>();
        Box c = new Box<Integer>();
        Box d = new Box<String>();

        // This one will not work as Rectangle does not implement Comparable!
        Box e = new Box<Rectangle>(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

> Why is it legal to create `new Box();` and  `new Box<Integer>();` ? Is it because `Box` is comparable?

No, it is because `Integer` or raw types in `new Box();` **are comparable**.